# Filepond req.body is empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, file-upload, filepond

I've just started using filepond library in react and I've managed to set most of it up. The problem I'm getting is that when the POST request is sent to the back end, the request body is empty, where as I understand it should contain the uploaded file data.

Any ideas on what might be causing the problem? The state (profilePicture) is being correctly updated on each image upload.

This is my code:

```
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/Modal'
import { useContext, useState } from 'react'
import ProfileContext from '../../../context/ProfileContext'

// Import React FilePond
import { FilePond, registerPlugin } from 'react-filepond'
// Import FilePond styles
import 'filepond/dist/filepond.min.css'
// Import the Image EXIF Orientation and Image Preview plugins
// Note: These need to be installed separately
// `npm i filepond-plugin-image-preview filepond-plugin-image-exif-orientation --save`
import FilePondPluginImageExifOrientation from 'filepond-plugin-image-exif-orientation'
import FilePondPluginImagePreview from 'filepond-plugin-image-preview'
import FilePondPluginFileValidateType from 'filepond-plugin-file-validate-type'
import FilePondPluginFileEncode from 'filepond-plugin-file-encode'

import 'filepond-plugin-image-preview/dist/filepond-plugin-image-preview.css'

// Register the plugins
registerPlugin(FilePondPluginImageExifOrientation, FilePondPluginImagePreview, FilePondPluginFileValidateType, FilePondPluginFileEncode)

export default function ProfilePictureModal({showProfilePictureModal, setShowProfilePictureModal}) {

    const [profilePicture, setProfilePicture] = useState([])


    const fileTypes = ['image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/png', 'image/gif']

    return (
        <div className='profilePictureModal'>
            <Modal show={showProfilePictureModal} onHide={() => {
                    setProfilePicture([])
                    setShowProfilePictureModal(false)
                }}>
                <Modal.Header closeButton>
                    <Modal.Title>Edita tu foto de perfil</Modal.Title>
                </Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Body>

                <FilePond
                    files={profilePicture}
                    onupdatefiles={setProfilePicture}
                    allowMultiple={false}
                    dropOnPage
                    server={{
                        process: {
                            url: 'http://localhost:3001/profile/profilePicture',
                            headers: {
                                Authorization: `${localStorage.getItem('accessToken')}`,
                            }
                        }
                    }}
                    name='profilePicture'
                    labelIdle='Drag & Drop your files or <span class="filepond--label-action">Browse</span>'
                />
                </Modal.Body>
                
                <Modal.Footer>
                    <button className='btn btn-secondary' type='button' onClick={() => {
                        setProfilePicture([])
                        setShowProfilePictureModal(false)
                    }}>Cancelar</button>

                    <button className='btn btn-primary' type='submit' onClick={e => {
                        // e.preventDefault()
                        if (profilePicture) {
                        setShowProfilePictureModal(false)
                    }}}>Guardar</button>

                </Modal.Footer>
            </Modal>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: I'd start by checking if you can see the `POST` request in your developer tools network tab. If you inspect the details you should be able to see the request body. If it shows the file you know the file is being posted and you can switch your attention to the server. If not, you can focus on fixing the client.